# Making the slider value change only from binding value

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to make the slider value to be set only from data binding.I dont want users to be able to change the slider value manually. This is the snippet. any suggestions on how to do it.

```
<Slider  x:Name="Serverslider"  Value="{Binding Value}"   

                               />
```

Any attribute i am missing?

Comment: `<Slider x:Name="Serverslider" Value="{Binding Value}" IsEnabled="False" />`

The user won't be able to interact with the slider but binding still works.

Comment: @wojtek Thanks. IsEnabled works but it causes other issues like the foreground property doesnt work . I want the filled property of slider to blue ,which doesnt seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wojtek suggests, you can use IsEnabled="False" to disable input from affecting the Slider.  You get this:

Now, you have the additional requirement of needing to change the fill color of the Slider.  Here you have two options:

1. Retemplate the Slider and change the "Disabled" visual state to look how you want it.  In Blend, right-click the Slider and choose "Edit Template > Edit a Copy".  Then, locate the colors you wish to change.  Here, these are going to be the fill color, the Thumb Background, and the Thumb BorderBrush for the Disabled state.  For example, change the following XAML:

   ```
   <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
     <Storyboard>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
     <Storyboard>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Orange"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   ```

   Note: Edit the parts marked "Vertical*" if you care about the vertical Slider template.
   Example code: https://github.com/finnigantime/Samples/tree/master/examples/Win8Xaml/Slider_RetemplateDisabledState
2. If all Disabled Sliders in your app look the same, you can override the "theme resources" that are used to draw the Disabled Slider in your app.xaml:

   ```
   <Application>
     <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Green" />
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Lime" />
       </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

   Example Code: https://github.com/finnigantime/Samples/tree/master/examples/Win8Xaml/Slider_OverrideDisabledResources